# Why is the Windows API less straight forward than other APIs?

Tags: windows, winapi, api-design

The Windows APIs don't seem to me to be as straight forward as you might expect.  To me, they are somewhat convoluted fashion?

Is this is an effect of keeping backwards compatibility?

Is Microsoft's main goal to push developers to higher level abstractions like ATL/MFC, VB, and/or .net?

It's my first time using the Win32 API and calls like `FindFirstFile` are making me a firm believer in the UNIX philosophy where the APIs seem to accomplish 90% of the flexibility at 10% of the effort. Then again there seems to be some unique cases that warrant using calls such as `fcntl` on *nix type machines where they'd be integral to the actual call on Windows.

... or am I just missing a fundamental paradigm?

Comment: Would have had more chances to stay open if it wasn't stated so bluntly...

Comment: Backwards compatability.  Sucks to be popular.

Comment: Damn!  I was half way finished my answer.

Comment: @Novikov - Why don't you rephrase your question so it's not a "Why do you suck?" type of question.  .... at least if you sincerely want to know the answer.

Comment: @John - Well if it fits in a comment maybe you can stuff it in there. I really doubt there'll be 3 more votes to reopen.

Comment: Personally Win32 causes me much less hair loss than the horror that is ATL.

Comment: and one to close.  This really is little more than a rant

Comment: I adjusted the question.  I hope this was inline with your original intent (without the rant part ;-).  also, some people don't like the paradigm word, if you don't feel it fits, you can remove it.

Comment: @John - Thanks John that's a less offensive way of relaying my question, however I decided to close it lest a torch carrying mob show up at my doorstep.

Comment: Win32 API is old, and has a number of wrappers... MFC, ATL, WTL, .NET Framework...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things to keep in mind:

1. It was designed about 20 years ago, and was largely based on earlier versions of Windows which were designed a decade before that.
2. It's based on C, so a GetString() function will needs to have a design like

   ```
   bool GetString( char* stringBuffer, int bufferLen)
   ```

   instead of the

   ```
   char* GetString(void)
   ```

   that any other language would have.
3. Backwards compatability is job 1 with this API, because every line of Windows code Microsoft owns is built on top of the Windows API